# How can I fix my internet connection when " my computer appears to be correctly configured"

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, internet-connection, ipv6

I am new to this website, I don't know if my question is an off topic question, or even if this is the suitable place to ask. Please  tell me if I am in the wrong place.

Since  some days I ma facing a problem with my internet connection. Before, every thing was okay, the  internet works fine. 
The problem start with being unable to connect to any web page, when trying diagnosing the problem in control panel , I get the massage

"Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding "

Note: I have a wire connection. I  have a windows 7  opertating system.

At first I suppose that the problem is general in the residence where I live, however  I detect that the problem is just happening with me. 
I try enter into properties of the " Local Area Connection".  Then for  "IPV4" and  "IPV6" and set the properties as  " Obtain an IP address automatically" and  "Obtain DNS server address automatically ". However this did not solve the problem.

Any suggestions?
I would appreciate any help .

Comment: Have you tried opening a command prompt and using the ipcofig /release then ipcofig /renew? Could possibly help?  And power cycle your modem and router before you do this.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I'd use ipconfig /flushdns rather than renew and release though...

Comment: Also, what happens if you set the dns to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4? If that doesn't work either, you might need to reinstall your network card drivers.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin  I will try them, however is it possible to ask about these two commands? what they do ?

Comment: @LPChip Sorry but how can I change (reset ) the dns  ?

Comment: @Nizar ipconfig /release stops the network connection, ipconfig /renew creates a new one

Comment: @Nizar in command prompt enter ipconfig /flushdns to flush the cache. you need to change the IPv4 settings where you found them to be: Receive from DHCP server, and check: manually enter. Then enter 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: Also listen to what @LPChip is saying basically it flushes out your DNS so do what he said and use the ipcofig /flushdns are you having trouble accessing the internet on any of your other devices?

Comment: @LPChip sorry but what did you mean by " you need to change the IPv4 settings where you found them to be " ? You mean I have to enter into properties of the "Local Area connection " ?

Comment: @Nazir, you wrote:  I try enter into properties of the " Local Area Connection". Then for "IPV4" and "IPV6" and set the properties as " Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically ". Now, instead of setting obtain DNS automatically, choose enter manually, and enter 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4  (only do this for IPv4)

Answer (score 0):

Who is your ISP?

Check your DNS server by doing an  ipconfig/all . 
Always make sure that the DNS Servers match with the DNS of your ISP. If it does not match, just set your DNS servers to manual and enter your ISP's DNS servers.